# Dividing a data set into segments with consistent inner behavior, using segmentation algorithms and metrics for consistency

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, classification, variance, timeseries-segmentation

**Context of the problem:**

I have signal data which was recorded in a software system and which shows the runtime of multiple processes over time. In total there are more than 900 processes each having roughly 400 reading points. The data is stored in an m x n matrix with roughly 900 rows (one process per row) and 400 columns (reading points/runtime values).

The following figure shows all of the processes:

[image: All processes]

For easier observation and analysis I filtered the data set, leaving only the 23 most relevant processes:

[image: Filtered processes]

The software system (e.g. car), that the processes were recorded in, was performing different tasks (e.g. acceleration, braking) resulting in runtime changes of the processes over time. The final goal of this work is to divide above data set (containing multitple processes) into segments, with each segment having "consistent inner behavior". Consistent inner behavior has not been defined yet. In the context of above filtered data set, a segment that could qualify for having consistent inner behavior is between reading points 225 and 310, as in most of the processes "something is happening" simultaneously in that range.

To illustrate the idea of consistent inner behavior in a single signal, I prepared following test signal with a possible segmentation:

[image: Test signal with intuitive segmentation]

The signal has been divided into five segments with two segments containing values between 50 and 60, and the three remaining segments containing values between 0 and 30. Intuitively, dividing the signal into five segments seems to be the ideal segmentation and guarantees that each segment has relative consistent inner behavior (in relation to the other segments, the data, etc.).

**Coming to the questions:**

> What are appropriate methods for dividing a data set with multiple processes into an optimal number of segments? For single and simple signals/processes the segmentation seems quite intuitive and easy, for multiple processes which have a lot of noise and different behaviors not.

> How could consistent inner behavior be defined and what metrics can be used to "measure" segments for consistent behavior?

The two questions above go hand in hand, as a segmenation with less segments (or the minimization of segments) will intuitively be preferred, but having a segment for each data point will give the best result for consistent inner behavior of each segment. So the minimization of the number of segments on the one hand, and its maximization due to the consistency of segments on the other hand "work against each other".

My first approach for solving above problem was using variance. The idea is to start with an arbitrary number of segments with the segmentation lines being equally spaced to each other. For the test signal, this presegmentation could look something like this:

[image: Test sinal with presegmentation]

The variance is calculated for each segment with following formula:

$$Var(S) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(X_i - \mu)^2}{n}$$

$$with$$

\begin{array}{}
S - \text{segment containing data} & X_i - \text{i}^{th} \text{ data point of segment} \\
\mu - \text{mean of data in segment} & n - \text{number of data points in segment} \\
\end{array}

Now, if needed, each segmentation line can be moved with the goal of minimizing the variance of two neighboring segments that are affected by moving respective line. Doing this for all segments iteratively will minimize the variance of the segments. Ideally, this will lead to a segmentation with each segment having consistent inner behavior. However, the question remains if variance can be used for finding segments with consistent inner behavior. For the test signal, using variance for segmentation leads to the same result as the intuitive approach:

[image: Segmentation with variance]

The problem here is that using variance for segmenting a process requires a presegmentation. Using an algorithm which determines the right number of segments would be difficult, as having one data point per segment would give the best result for minimizing the variance of each segment (this brings us back to the maximization and minimization problems mentioned above). Also, the question remains if using variance for segmentation guarantees that each segment shows relatively consistent inner behavior.

**Summing it up:**

- I have a data set with multiple processes which, in its entirety, should be divided into segments,
- The processes or rather each segment should show consistent inner behavior,
- I need a method which can be used to divide the data set into an optimal amount of segments by finding the tradeoff between minimizing the number of segments, and maximizing them due to consistent inner behavior, and
- (If possible) I need a definition of consistent inner behavior and a metric which can measure it.

Please excuse the theoretical and cryptic nature of this question. Right now I am writing a position paper on the topic which I will finish within the next days. I can make it available and link it here once it is published and if desired.

Comment: Can you link your paper? :)

Comment: @JonNordby sure! Here is the link to the paper: [Analysis of Patterns in Software Signals](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/357928742_Analysis_of_Patterns_in_Recorded_Signals_of_Software_Systems_With_a_Variance_Based_Segmentation_Algorithm). Thanks for your interest in the topic. If you have any questions regarding my post here or the paper feel free to write me. 
I am currently writing a thesis on this topic which is quite advanced and already covers some of the things asked in this post. If interested, I can publish a version of the thesis as well.

Answer (score 1):

A subsequence like this is sometimes referred to as a [time series snippet](https://matrixprofile.org/posts/what-are-time-series-snippets). The linked resource describes how to identify such using the [matrix profile](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/MatrixProfile.html).

Another approach is to apply a generic time-series segmentation to get candidate segments, and then compare the segments to each-other using some distance measure. This could be Dynamic Time Warping to allow for some time variations in the segments.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Following your links, I found these two papers which apply the matrix profile and helped me understand the model: [Matrix Profile VIII: Domain Agnostic Online Semantic Segmentation at Superhuman Performance Levels](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/Segmentation_ICDM.pdf) and [Domain agnostic online semantic segmentation for multi-dimensional time series](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6373324/pdf/10618_2018_Article_589.pdf).